# How can I understand 'discontinuous on rationals' vs 'discontinuous on reals' intuitively?

Tags: analysis, functions

Here is two functions :

1. $$f\colon (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}
   \frac1q,  & \text{if $x \in \Bbb Q$  with $ x=\frac{p}q$ for $p,q \in \Bbb N$ coprime} \\
   0, & \text{if $x \notin \Bbb Q $}
   \end{cases}$$

(also known as Thomae function)  and

2. $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 & x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\ 
   0 & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}$$

---

The first one is continuous on irrationals, not for rationals.

The second one is discontinuous on reals.

And this is a beginning of the problem.

Since (Real numbers) = (Rational numbers) + (Irrational numbers),

If a function $f$ is discontinuous on rationals(or irrationals), I think $f$ should discontinuous for irrationals(rationals) too. (like the second function.)

But for the first one, it is discontinuous on rationals, not for irrationals.

Is there any hint or explanation about difference of these intuitively?

Comment: What makes you think that is a function is discontinuous at the rationals, then it must also be discontinuous at the irrationals?

Comment: First statement is readably provable.

Comment: Never say "should".

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the function whose value is 0 for every non-null real number, and 1 for 0. This function is continuous everywhere except on 0. So discontinuity on a single isolated point is possible. The difficulty is understanding why it is still possible for a (countable) infinite number of discontinuity points.

Rationals and irrationals play little role here, apart from their density and cardinals. A property of Thomae function is: $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \{ x, \left | f(x) \right | \ge \varepsilon \} $ has finite cardinal. Any function with this property on an interval is continuous almost everywhere on this interval, with value 0. This is because, the number of points where the function's value is $\ge \varepsilon$ being finite, given an $x$ where $f(x) = 0$ it is always possible to find an interval around $x$ with none of these points.

If your doubt comes from the intuition that continuity points of a function cannot be *any* set, then you are right. The set of continuous points of a function is a $G_\delta$, i.e. a countable intersection of open sets.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$, so a function that is continuous on all rationals and discontinuous on all reals is not possible. But $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ *is* a $G_\delta$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set